# How to use "increment_build_number" in xcworkspace projects?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, fastlane

I am trying to automate my build process with fastlane in my react native project. I am following [this article](https://carloscuesta.me/blog/shipping-react-native-apps-with-fastlane/). In `increment_build_number` action I couldn't find any option to specify the .xcworkspace project. I tried using `workspace` tag, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The action does not have a `workspace` parameter: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/#parameters

`increment_build_number` is more or less a wrapper for `agvtool` from Apple. That tool unfortunately only works on `xcodeproj` files: http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/agvtool/ You actually don't even specify the file, it looks for it in the folder you are executing the command in.

Which is also why `increment_build_number` only uses the `xcodeproj` parameter to change the directory before running the command: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/04ef48fad041eb6c62e8015264df781d3bfc9983/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/increment_build_number.rb#L15-L21

You will probably have to modify your usage to specify the xcode project (that should exist next to the workspace anyway) or execute it in a way so the action can find it automatically.

Comment: Thanks :). I am working with react-native and my packages require Pods configuration. I can't shift to .xcodeproj rightaway. I tried Automatic execution and it didn't find the .xcworkspace file.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work with `.xcworkspace` files as the tool works on the project files. Doesn't your project _also_ have a project file that can be edited? I don't know anything about React Native, but I would try to find the `.xcodeproj` file and let it work on that.

Comment: I understand. Thanks @janpio